# gcloud auth login proxy issue

Tags: gcloud, http-proxy

When I attempt to authenticate with GCloud using the command `gcloud auth login`, I receive the following error message:

```
Your browser has been opened to visit:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=3...

ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication. Try running again with --no-browser.
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) Could not reach the login server. A potential cause of this could be because you are behind a proxy. Please set the environment variables HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY to the address of the proxy in the format "protocol://address:port" (without quotes) and try again.
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

This issue arose for me when I'd set the environment variables `$HTTP_PROXY` and`$HTTPS_PROXY`.

The solution is simply to unset the variables:

- `unset HTTP_PROXY`
- `unset HTTPS_PROXY`